# Multiple INNER JOINs SQL Server Compact Edition

Tags: sql, vb.net, inner-join, multiple-tables

I am trying to do multiple joins within a single query in SQL Server CE. I know that SQL Server CE doesn't support multiple SELECTs but I can't find any information on multiple INNER JOINs. I keep getting token errors on `ProjectItemMaster` (after the FROM) and the first INNER JOIN. Warning this is a big ugly query used to generate reports.

`GetCutSheetDataByCustPnumTagQuery` as defined as:

```
SELECT ReportCalculations.ItemNumber, ReportCalculations.PartNumber,
       ReportCalculations.calcWidth, ReportCalculations.calcHeight, 
       ReportCalculations.calcQuantity, ReportCalculations.Description,
       ReportCalculations.PrintonCutSheet, ProjectItemMaster.Quantity, 
       ProjectItemMaster.HingeDirection, ProjectItemMaster.ItemDescription,
       ProjectItemMaster.MetalFinish, ProjectItemMaster.Width, 
       ProjectItemMaster.Height, ProjectItemMaster.CustomerID, 
       CustomerMaster.CustomerId AS Id_CM, ProjectItemMaster.GlassType,  
       ProjectItemMaster.Tag AS Expr1, ReportCalculations.Tag, 
       ProjectItemMaster.ItemNumber AS Expr2, ReportCalculations.CalcX, 
       ReportCalculations.CalcY, ProjectItemMaster.OpeningWidth,
       ProjectItemMaster.ReturnDirection, ProjectItemMaster.PanelDirection, 
       ProjectItemMaster.ReturnWidth, ProjectItemMaster.ButtressHeight,
       ProjectItemMaster.ButtressWidth, ProjectItemMaster.AvailThickness, 
       ProjectItemMaster.PanelThickness, ProjectItemMaster.Image,
       ProjectItemMaster.SoftwareVersion, ProjectItemMaster.DatabaseVersion, 
       ProdlineMaster.Series, ProdlineMaster.Report, ProjectItemMaster.Addons,
       ProjectItemMaster.PanelWidth, CustomerMaster.CustomerName, 
       ProjectMaster.WO, ProjectMaster.PO, ProdlineMaster.SeriesName, 
       ReportCalculations.Series AS Expr3
FROM ProjectItemMaster 
INNER JOIN CustomerMaster 
ON ProjectItemMaster.CustomerID = CustomerMaster.CustomerId 
INNER JOIN ReportCalculations 
ON ProjectItemMaster.Tag = ReportCalculations.Tag 
AND ProjectItemMaster.CustomerID = ReportCalculations.CustomerID 
AND ProjectItemMaster.ProjectNumber = ReportCalculations.ProjectNumber 
INNER JOIN ProdlineMaster 
ON ReportCalculations.Series = ProdlineMaster.Series 
INNER JOIN ProjectMaster 
ON CustomerMaster.CustomerId = ProjectMaster.CustomerId 
AND ProjectItemMaster.ProjectNumber = ProjectMaster.ProjectNumber
WHERE (ReportCalculations.PrintonCutSheet = 'Y') 
AND (ProjectItemMaster.ProjectNumber = @ProjectNumber) 
AND (CustomerMaster.CustomerId = @CustomerID) 
AND (ProjectItemMaster.CustomerID = @CustomerID) 
AND (ProjectItemMaster.Tag = @TAG)
```

This is the function that Is executing the Query in VB.NET on the SQL Compact Database.

```
Public Function getCutSheetInfobyCustProdTag(ByRef customerID As String, 
                                             ByRef projectNumber As Integer, 
                                             ByVal tag As String) 
                                      As System.Data.DataTable

    Dim mydata As New DataTable
    GetCutSheetDataByCustPnumTagQuery.Parameters.Clear()
    GetCutSheetDataByCustPnumTagQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectNumber", 
                                                                 projectNumber)
    GetCutSheetDataByCustPnumTagQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", 
                                                                    customerID)
    GetCutSheetDataByCustPnumTagQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TAG", tag)

    Try
       splConnection.Open()
       Dim reader As SqlCeDataReader = GetCutSheetDataByCustPnumTagQuery.ExecuteReader
       mydata.Load(reader)
    Catch ex As Exception
       MessageBox.Show("Problem with reportcalculations table", "Error", 
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
       ' Return False
    Finally
       splConnection.Close()
    End Try
    'Return True
    Return mydata

End Function
```

If I can't uses multiple INNER JOINs I can I break the query down into a number of different queries but I would prefer not to. So it is easier to maintain a SQL Server CE and an SQL Server version of the program.

Comment: At a quick glance, your statement _looks_ fine, although I don't know enough about Compact to judge about `JOIN`s (although I can't imagine they would be - you'd be disabling most of the reason d'etre for an RDBMS...).  If it's complaining about the `FROM` clause, try removing individual selected columns until it disappears.  I also reccommend putting _everything possible_ in the `JOIN`s, and **not** in the `WHERE` clause; save your `WHERE` clauses for restriction of the table referenced by `FROM` (or emulating `EXCEPTION` joins)

Comment: After @X-Zero rearranged the query I no longer get a `SQLCeException` on the FROM token. I am now getting a `SQLCeException` `Data conversion failed. [ OLE DB status value (if known) = 0 ]`. After some research the problem seems to come from schema not matching or NULL values.

Comment: The exception you listed feels a little vague - I would check that all your comparison columns are the same data types.

Comment: I double checked and all the comparison columns are the same datatype and precision. A few columns have been added since the query was originally written but they are not included. Could have be causing the problem?

Comment: No, the query won't care about the additional columns (it isn't able to tell if you didn't include the columns because you didn't want them, or they didn't exist at the time).  We need a more specific exception...

Comment: I figured out that `ProjectItemMaster` isn't being filled with data by the program. I am pretty confident that is causing the exception.

Comment: Turns out that that Table `ProjectItemMaster` was being filled correctly. I had `CustomerID` as a `Integer` when it needed to be a `String`. After fixing that I am still getting the same message. So ran the query outside of the program, with Visual Studio's Server Explore. When I did that the query executed correctly and generated the correct output. So I guess it is time to dig through the SqlServerCe API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently SQL Compact doesn't like it when you give Query parameters that do not have their type and length explicitly stated. The query kept trying to convert the `CustomerID` which was "987654" to a numeric. I figured this out because hard coding the values into the query made it run fine but when I used @CustomerID the program threw an expection. So switching from parameters.addwithvalue(Name, Value) to Parameters.add(Name, Type, Length) solved the problems.

```
 Public Function getCutSheetInfobyCustProdTag(ByRef customerID As String, ByRef projectNumber As Integer, ByVal tag As String) As System.Data.DataTable

        Dim mydata As New DataTable
        GetCutSheetDataByCustPnumTagQuery.Parameters.Clear()
        GetCutSheetDataByCustPnumTagQuery.Parameters.Add("@ProjectNumber", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int)
        GetCutSheetDataByCustPnumTagQuery.Parameters("@ProjectNumber").Value = projectNumber
        GetCutSheetDataByCustPnumTagQuery.Parameters.Add("@CustomerID", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 25)
        GetCutSheetDataByCustPnumTagQuery.Parameters("@CustomerID").Value = customerID
        GetCutSheetDataByCustPnumTagQuery.Parameters.Add("@TAG", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50)
        GetCutSheetDataByCustPnumTagQuery.Parameters("@TAG").Value = tag

        Try
            splConnection.Open()
            Dim reader As SqlCeDataReader = GetCutSheetDataByCustPnumTagQuery.ExecuteReader
            mydata.Load(reader)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Problem with reportcalculations table", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

        Finally
            splConnection.Close()
        End Try

        Return mydata
    End Function
```

Thank you @X-Zero for your help